# Trying to run existing Xamarin Native in Jetbrains Rider IDE

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, rider, xamarin-native

I have an existing xamarin based project. It does work in Visual Studio 2022. Since, intellij  based IDE (Rider) does provide some good support for android, I was trying to run it in Rider.

But, stuck with this problem for quite sometime now.

Tried looking everywhere. Couldn't find any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank  you.

[image: Project Error]

[image: Rider version]

[image: DotNet version]

Comment: please do not post errors as images

Comment: What is the TargetFramework of the "core" project?

Comment: @Cheesebaron `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: And issue persists if you clean bin/obj folders and do another restore